# How to step down DC 19~17V to DC 6V?

Tags: dc, ldo

Please help me to looking for a cheap and simple chip or circuit that can step down DC 19~17V to DC 6V with a load of about 200 mA.

I have tried to use an LDO like AMS1117 to drop it violently, but it is very hot and the temperature is very scary.

Comment: Violence is never the solution... ;)

Comment: Google _buck converter_. Try TI Webench.

Comment: Is 2W resistor simple and cheap enough?

Answer (score 2):

A linear regulator will waste a maximum power of:

(19V-6V)*0.2A = 2.6W

That will be turned into heat. It is too much for a SOT SMD package. If you want SMD you can use a regulator in DPAK form factor with a large copper area for cooling for example the whole ground plane on the board, or TO-220 with a small heat sink.

To avoid wasting power and unwanted heat you can use a buck converter, the simplest is to get a [ready-made](https://fr.farnell.com/en-FR/w/c/power-line-protection/power-supplies/dc-dc-converters/dc-dc-non-isolated-board-mount-converters-adjustable-output?input-voltage-dc-min=4v%7C4.5v%7C4.75v%7C6.5v%7C9v%7C10v%7C11v&input-voltage-dc-max=27vdc%7C28v%7C30v%7C32v%7C36v%7C53v&range=inc-in-stock&sort=P_PRICE) one. 6V isn't a common output voltage option for the fixed output ones, so I went to the adjustable category. For 5V there would be a lot more options.

You can also roll your own, there are hundreds of buck chips that will do the job, but if you're only going to build one board... personally I'd rather pay a little bit more for a readymade buck than spend the time to select the parts, do the layout, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Buck regulator module:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/332711109230?hash=item4d7720a26e:g:WSoAAOSw-KJdlD2X&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA0HkS4HxKD3w2Zz5CksGGI7%2Fny9hCpCgbhjNo3iOcTnIICCWFiNbtKn81GR%2FEjt%2BXe3JV1Uh5Xi0BMB%2BvW7PGXyvNrr6Bcm0x0vNHZb%2BKuYu1xh%2FeFBILACdEn0EF1bskwPvc4Koh95I7ssfXH%2B7PLCprEcBLNJEP5fMTyIUc1y%2BAOdmE5Tb50T%2Fza0MT9%2BhGtu%2BZSlJSiQ1t2c0FaImp6D1pkCnSWvm%2BRqzWBKgGtkpJpkCGw3V1O%2F18IrGSL4yV904kScsby8RpWv4N2IreTzM%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR7Lb7oblYQ

Smaller, cheaper, longer lead time:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/175569869721?hash=item28e0c79b99:g:AhcAAOSwnwth57VL&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA8KGW2G4PssMeDdGvrOA977bjDul6YAk4Ll7KPUN4wXEuLEYe8sJa1%2BRm1VsSBM%2B3kT77kmQrbxiw4jP4Oyh0QkgEG7rGd2T%2FQ9U0jZUgvPYw832SXJSuE%2BNphfUX3YT31MCSgAkTRYbZVSKeFieNWLt1F4QhxMhzHMclPTdotlOpl834PYSPZ1HHXY%2FRYKIBYbEJDaolK3QfBjA6%2Fdq227QVExc5pTc964GQPspDbbF6JoDyOmil3qvSm0aoA2m6TVThd9TL9FDpEJ3VYXnTaALumpwrYkiH%2F8%2Fk%2BTZ9HxdAPqxcrPesKycWh%2Fgdpy2Wtg%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR7Tb7oblYQ

.